# Why do I need db_owner to open a connection

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, roles

I've created a Sql Server database (through Visual Studio) and in it I created a user in the database. I gave that user membership in the db_datareader and db_datawriter roles.

When I try to open a connection I get the below exception. If I add the user to the db_owner role, then it works. Why? Shouldn't db_datareader be sufficient to open a connection?

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at LicenseLibrary.Database.AzureDataAccess.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<ExecuteAction>b__0() in C:\git\Store\LicenseLibrary\Database\AzureDataAccess.cs:line 150

Inner Exception 1:
Win32Exception: No process is on the other end of the pipe
```

**Update:**
I am creating the DB using a number of .sql scripts that VisualStudio runs to create the database. The ones for this are (lines with "GO;" removed:

```
CREATE USER [readwrite] WITH PASSWORD = N'**************';
CREATE USER [readonly] WITH PASSWORD = N'************';
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [readonly];
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [readwrite];
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [readwrite];
```

[image]

Also, it's a weird exception for failing on a role it wants - saying there's no process.

I have an example in [TestDatabaseRoles.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/emraaeej7kemk6s/TestDatabaseRoles.zip?dl=0) - 3 lines of code tomake it happen (need the database in the zip too).

Comment: There's no reason db_owner would be required to connect to a database.  Can you provide a simplified repro? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - updated. Please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: I couldn't repro, even on a localdb instance.  Can you add a repro for the connecting code?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I just added a link to a sample. The sample is just 3 lines of code. I think you need the DB to see it happen so the sample has that too. Thank you for looking at this!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as background that error message is a generic connection failure message whose details are withheld from the client for security reasons.  You need to look in the SQL Logs to see the real errors.

`readwrite` is a contained database user, so lots of things can fail.

The login failure message in the SQL Log will be something like:

> Login failed for user 'readwrite'. Reason: Could not find a login
>   matching the name provided. [CLIENT: `<named pipe>`]

if contained database authentication is not configured, or

> Login failed for user 'readwrite'. Reason: Failed to open the specified database. [CLIENT: `<local machine>`]

if the database name is wrong or the user lacks the CONNECT permission, or

> Login failed for user 'readwrite'. Reason: Password did not match that for the user provided. [Database: 'Database1'] [CLIENT: `<local machine>`]

if the password is incorrect.

In summary, all of the following must be true for the connection to succeed:

1) The instance must have contained database authentication enabled, with

```
exec sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;
```

2) The database must be set to `partial` containment.

```
alter database Database1 set containment = partial
```

3) The user must have the CONNECT permission (which db_owner already has).

```
grant connect to readwrite
```

Comment: First off, thank you! Second, out of curiosity, how can a user do anything if it can't connect?

Comment: A user can be impersonated and own objects without the ability to connect.